# Specific row withing a DataTable

Tags: asp.net, linq, datatable

I have a data table which has a "Total" column. I want to be able to get a specific rows "Total" not all rows.

```
public void maxValue()
    {
        string pass = (String)Session["name"];
        DataTable table = (DataTable)Session["CocaCola"];
        int total = table.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Total"));
        int totalAllowed = table.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<Int32>("Total Allowed"));

        if (total >= totalAllowed)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Total value exceeded the maximum of " + totalAllowed;
        }
        else if (total < totalAllowed)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Total value which is allowed :" + totalAllowed;
        }
        if (pass.Equals("Low"))
        {
            Label1.Text = "You are not allowed any assets at this Stage";
            //SNS.Checked = false;
            //TT.Checked = false;
            //Music.Checked = false;
            //SNS.Enabled = false;
            //TT.Enabled = false;
            //Music.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

As you can see my method works but add the column up which i dont want to do. How would i go about changing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
int yourTargetindex = 0; //Change this to get the value of your target element
int total =(from row in table.AsEnumerable()
            select row.Field<int>("Total")).ElementAt(yourTargetindex);
  //This will return the first value of "total" in the DataTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have* to use linq. DataTable has built-in methods for this kind of operations:

```
var selectedTotal = table.Compute("sum(Total)", "columnX == 'x'");
```

This tell the table to calculate the sum of all `Total` cells in rows where `columnX` has the specified value.

Of course you can use linq. You would need to add a `Where()` before you calculate the sum.